# Can the US president be impeached through a petition?

Tags: united-states, president, impeachment

Can the US president be impeached when citizens collect enough signatures on a petition?

Answer (score 11):

No.

There is no binding petition process on federal level in the United States.

The impeachment process according to [article 2, section 4 of the constitution](http://www.usconstitution.net/xconst_A2Sec4.html) can only be initiated by congress. They are only allowed to do so "for Treason, Bribery, or other high Crimes and Misdemeanors". But congress also define what "high Crimes and Misdemeanors" are in that context (the last time it was [lying about cheating on his wife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impeachment_of_Bill_Clinton)), so they basically start the process when they feel  like it.

Comment: The official reasons was lying while under oath, the lie was about cheating on his wife, but still perjury.

Comment: No, it wasn't lying about cheating on his wife. It's lying about sexual harrassment in the workplace - something [lesser men lost their jobs over unceremoniously](http://www.wsj.com/articles/SB111019724886272076) , high crimes or not. Their main crime being, apparently "not being a popular left wing politician"; since Clinton was vocally defended by the very same people who hate sexual harassment with a passion in any other context.